# Выделение и копирование текста в виртуальном терминале

Tags: linux, terminal

Как правильно осуществляется выделение, копирование и вставка текста в виртуальном терминале в Ubuntu?

пример:

```
#команда
$ wpa_passphrase <имя_точки_доступа> <ascii_ключ>

#вывод в терминале
network={
ssid="test"
psk="12345678"
psk=fe727aa8b64ac9b3f54c72432da14faed933ea511ecab1 5bbc6c52e7522f709a
}
```

Как правильно выделить, скопировать и вставить в следующие команды `hex` ключ?

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вы подразумеваете под терминалом: [виртуальный терминал](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C) или [иксовый эмулятор терминала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Comment: Например, `wpa_passphrase <имя> <ключ>  > text.txt` Далее открываем в vi файл text.txt, копируем в буфер нужную инфу и вставляем в нужном месте в командную строку

Comment: Под терминалом я имею ввиду консоль которая доступна без GUI

Comment: @user199588, это называется виртуальный терминал. по поводу подробностей см. ссылку в первом комментарии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**если имеется «мышь»**, то можно установить пакет [gpm](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gpm), и использовать её для копирования (надо выделить фрагмент текста с помощью левой кнопки) и вставки в командную строку (с помощью средней кнопки). собственно, как и при работе с *эмулятором терминала*, запущенным под управлением *x-сервера*.

---

**если «мыши» нет**, то понадобится [мультиплексор терминала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80).

например, с помощью запущенной программы [gnu/screen](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) (пакет обычно называется [screen](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/screen)) можно [действовать так](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Copy-and-Paste.html#Copy-and-Paste):

1. перейти в режим копирования/листания с помощью любой из комбинаций: <kbd>C-a [</kbd>, <kbd>C-a C-[</kbd>, <kbd>C-a `<ESC>`</kbd> (подразумевается, что вы не меняли умолчальный метасимвол <kbd>a</kbd> с помощью команды [escape](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Command-Character.html#Command-Character)).
2. [переместить курсор](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Movement.html#Movement) с помощью клавиш <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> и <kbd>l</kbd> (т.н. *vi-стиль* управления курсором) в начало выделяемого фрагмента и [отметить](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Marking.html#Marking) его с помощью пробела.
3. переместить курсор в конец выделяемого фрагмента и отметить его повторным нажатием пробела. *screen* вернётся в «нормальный» режим работы.
4. [вставить](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Paste.html#Paste) ранее выделенный фрагмент в текущую позицию с помощью любой из комбинаций: <kbd>C-a ]</kbd>, <kbd>C-a C-]</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

например:

```
$ key=`wpa_passphrase <имя_точки_доступа> <ascii_ключ> | grep -E ^psk=[^\"] | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
$ do_next_command_with_argument $key
```

Копи-паст в привычном понимании этого слова без мышки никак не получится ИМХО.